# Регулярный запуск параметризованой сборки с заданными параметрами

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Jenkins, параметризованная сборка ([Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)), имеющая несколько строковых параметров.

Хочу настроить регулярное выполнение сборки с заданными значениями параметров (это будут не дефолтные значения).

Пока что лучшее, что придумал — создать новую регулярную сборку, которая при запуске будет просто запускать эту через [Parametrized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). Но это выглядит как-то слишком сложно.

Подозреваю, что есть способ настроить регулярное выполнение *с параметрами* в самой сборке.

Comment: Важно, чтобы она оставалась параметризованной?

Comment: @Nofate ну да, у нее есть и другие случаи запуска.

Comment: У меня сборка запускается через АПИ - по факту это один запрос сделанный через curl. Если религия позволяет поставить в cron вызов curl, который будет запускать сборку - то это вполне себе вариант.

Comment: @newman точно, ParameterizedTrigger Plugin позволяет передавать параметры в URL.

Comment: @newman у меня сейчас просто работает другая сборка, которая по расписанию дергает эту с несколькими наборами параметров. Так оказалось удобнее отслеживать фейлы.

Answer (score 1):

Походу только через это:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin

но судя по комментам там пока водятся баги.

Comment: Ну не только, давно есть костыльный способ, описанный в комментарии выше: «работает другая сборка, которая по расписанию дергает эту с несколькими наборами параметров».